# Calculate $P(X\leq 1\mid Y\leq0)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

I need to calculate $P(X\leq1\mid Y\leq0)$

I've found that

$$P(X\leq1\mid Y\leq0)=\frac{P(X\leq1,Y\leq0)}{P(Y\leq0)}$$

But is it true that

$$P(X\leq1,Y\leq0)=P(X=0,Y=-1)+P(X=0,Y=0)+P(X=1,Y=-1)+P(X=1,Y=0)$$

... if $P(X)$ can obtain values for $X=0,1,2$ and $P(Y)$ can obtain values for $Y=-1,0,1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true. The justification is that:

$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$ for $A\cap B=\emptyset$. So if you can divide an event into a family of disjoint (i.e. mutually exclusive) subevents, you may obtain the events probability through addition.